# How to add an image after finishing a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble with making an image pop up after the user filled in the form. I just need it to run the .png on the bottom of the form when all fields have been entered.
When the user selects the amount of people attending (max 5) that number of text boxes appears so it can be filled in with the name of the person.
Once the last name is filled in and the user presses enter I want an image to appear (a picture of a check mark - this is mandatory).

This is what I have:

In HTML:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Step 1</legend>
        How many people will be attending?
            <select name = step1 id="step1" onchange="showField()">
            <option value="0">Please Choose</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        <br>
        <div id="divName"></div>
        <img id="check" src="check.png">
        </fieldset> 
    </form>
```

In Javascript:

```
function showField() {
    var selectDropDown = $("#step1");
    var value = selectDropDown.val();
    var insertDiv = $("#divName");
    var innerHtmlString = "";
    if(value > 0){
        innerHtmlString = "<b>Please provide full names: </b> <br/>";
    }
    for(i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        innerHtmlString += "<i>Attendee " + (i+1) + " Name:</i> <input type='text' name='"+(i+1)+"' /> </br><br/>";
    }
    insertDiv.html(innerHtmlString);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ajax to send the form by javascript or jquery
you could use
[documentaion page](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

```
$('#myForm').ajaxComplete(function() {});
```

you could also use the ajax:complete event binded to your form.

```
$('#myform').on('ajax:complete' , function() {});
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I'm not allowed to use ajax for this, do you know how to solve it just using javascript and html? FedeSc?

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `onChange` inside the select tag and insert one eventlistener inside the javascript, before the function.

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Step 1</legend>
    How many people will be attending?
        <select name = step1 id="step1">
        <option value="0">Please Choose</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    <br>
    <div id="divImage"></div>
    <img id="check" src="check.png">
    </fieldset> 
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("step1").addEventListener("change", showField);

function showField(){
  var selectDropDown = $("#step1");
  var value = selectDropDown.val();
  var insertDiv = $("#divImage");
  var innerHtmlString = "";
  if(value > 0){
      innerHtmlString = "<b>Please provide full names: </b> <br/>";
  }
  for(i = 0; i < value; i++){
      innerHtmlString += "<i>Attendee " + (i+1) + " Name:</i> <input type='text' name='"+(i+1)+"' /> </br><br/>";
  }
  insertDiv.html(innerHtmlString);
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hmr8p7o4/5/

Comment: Is there something else that I need to add to this?
This made my function to no longer function at all.

Comment: Have u added the jQuery library?

Comment: Yes I did, my code is working fine, I just want the image to appear after the form has been filled in by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Figured using a keypress was good:

This was from a friend of mine.

```
    $(document).on("keypress", function (e) {
if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13){
    $("#check").show();
}
```

Give the .png(or whatever) an ID and use "13"(code for enter) to fire it.